# C# how to binding the array to the button array

Tags: c#, winforms, button, data-binding, windows-forms-designer

I am practicing the structure of viewModel and databinding. I create the buttons and add them into an array so that I can easily manage them with a for loop. However, is seems that I make some mistake when I amd binding them.

Here are my code:

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    private ViewModel viewModel;
    private Button[] buttons;

    public MyForm (ViewModel viewModel)
    {
        this.viewModel = viewModel;
        InitializeComponent();

        buttons = new Button[]
        {
            button1, button2, button3, ...
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Length; ++i)
        {
            buttons[i].DataBindings.Add("Text", viewModel, "ButtonText[" + i + "]");
        }
    }

    (...)
}
```

and In my ViewModel

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private string[] buttonText;

    public string[] ButtonText
    {
        get
        {
            return buttonText;
        }
    }

    public ViewModel ()
    {
        buttonText = new string[]
        {
            "string1", "string2", "string3", ...
        };
    }

    (...)
}
```

when I run it, I get an `ArgumentException`

> System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot bind to the property or column "ButtonText[0]" on the DataSource. Parameter name: dataMember'

How should I modify my binding to get the correct program behavior?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind to the index item of the property.
If you consider that data-binding based on reflection, then you will see that viewmodel doesn't have public property of name "ButtonText[2]". DataMember name is just a string, data-binding will not be able to retrieve an index from there.

Instead you can have own property for every button for data-binding a button's text.
And still have it in a collection for other logic yo need to do in the loop.

If you have dynamic buttons, you can bind collection of button names and actions to the `DataGridView` with only one button column.